# Unable to change element position via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know PHP,VB.net but I'm beginner in JavaScript. I have a problem with animation. The first one is working, but second one not...

```
var elem = document.getElementById("PrviObjekat"); (this one is working)

var elem_drugi = document.getElementById("DrugiObjekat"); (this one not, it has no logic)...
```

However I it calls it don't works...

Full HTML/JS code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stilizacija.css"/>
<title>Animacija</title> 
<script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>   
</head>

<body>
<div id = "Animacija">
<p id = "PrviObjekat"> Dobro došli, ovo je prvi probni tekst.</p>
<p id = "DrugiObjekat">Ovo je drugi tekst...</p>
</div>  
<br>
<script>
function Animiraj() 
{
var elem = document.getElementById("PrviObjekat"); 
var elem_drugi = document.getElementById("DrugiObjekat");
var pos = 0;
var pos2 = 195;
var id = setInterval(frame_dole, 12);
function frame_dole() 
{
    if (pos == 150) 
    {
        clearInterval(frame_dole);
        id = setInterval(frame_gore, 12);
    } else {
        pos++; 
        elem.style.top = pos + 'px'; 
        elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
        elem_drugi.style.left = pos + 'px';
    }
}
function frame_gore() 
{
    if (pos == 0) 
    {
        clearInterval(id);
        id = setInterval(frame_dole, 12);
    } else {
        pos--; 
        elem.style.top = pos - 'px'; 
        elem.style.left = pos - 'px'; 
        elem_drugi.style.left = pos - 'px';
    }
}   
}               
var PrviKliknut = false;
$("#PrviObjekat").click(function()
{
if(PrviKliknut == false)
{
$("#PrviObjekat").css({"font-size" : "20px"});
PrviKliknut = true;
}else{
$("#PrviObjekat").css({"font-size" : "16px"});
PrviKliknut = false;
}
});     
$(document).ready(function() 
{
console.log("Dokument je učitan.");
Animiraj();
//$("#PrviObjekat").animate({ scrollTop: $("#TockaB").offset().top }, 1500);    
});     
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS code:

```
#Animacija
{
width: 550px;
height: 550px;
position: relative;
background: yellow;
}
#PrviObjekat 
{
width: 145px;
height: 75px;
position: absolute;
background: red;
}
#DrugiObjekat
{
background: green;
width: 100px;
height: 60px;
margin-left: 195px;
margin-top: 25px;
}
```

Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: why do you want to use getElementbyId when you are using JQuery?

Comment: try make #DrugiObjekat position: absolute

Answer (score 1):

```js
function Animiraj() 
{
var elem = document.getElementById("PrviObjekat"); 
var elem_drugi = document.getElementById("DrugiObjekat");
var pos = 0;
var pos2 = 195;
var id = setInterval(frame_dole, 12);
function frame_dole() 
{
    if (pos == 150) 
    {
        clearInterval(frame_dole);
        id = setInterval(frame_gore, 12);
    } else {
        pos++; 
        elem.style.top = pos + 'px'; 
        elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
        elem_drugi.style.left = pos + 'px';
      
    }
}
function frame_gore() 
{
    if (pos == 0) 
    {
        clearInterval(id);
        id = setInterval(frame_dole, 12);
    } else {
        pos--; 
        elem.style.top = pos - 'px'; 
        elem.style.left = pos - 'px'; 
        elem_drugi.style.left = pos - 'px';
      

    }
}   
}               
var PrviKliknut = false;
$("#PrviObjekat").click(function()
{
if(PrviKliknut == false)
{
$("#PrviObjekat").css({"font-size" : "20px"});
PrviKliknut = true;
}else{
$("#PrviObjekat").css({"font-size" : "16px"});
PrviKliknut = false;
}
});     
$(document).ready(function() 
{
console.log("Dokument je učitan.");
Animiraj();
//$("#PrviObjekat").animate({ scrollTop: $("#TockaB").offset().top }, 1500);    
});
```

```css
<style>
{
width: 550px;
height: 550px;
position: relative;
background: yellow;
}
#PrviObjekat 
{
width: 145px;
height: 75px;
position: absolute;
background: red;
}
#DrugiObjekat
{
background: green;
width: 100px;
height: 60px;
margin-left: 195px;
margin-top: 25px;
position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<div id = "Animacija">
<p id = "PrviObjekat"> Dobro došli, ovo je prvi probni tekst.</p>
<p id = "DrugiObjekat">Ovo je drugi tekst...</p>
</div>  
<br>
</body>
```

**

```
#DrugiObjekat
{
background: green;
width: 100px;
height: 60px;
margin-left: 195px;
margin-top: 25px;
position: absolute;
}
```

**HTML elements are positioned static by default.
Static positioned elements are not affected by the top, bottom, left, and right properties.**

Comment: Are you going to explain your answer or make us play a game of spot-the-difference?

Comment: @j08691 i forgot .my mistake..take a look

Comment: "Static positioned elements are not affected by" ... so what you need to do is change ... X ... to ... Y  -- and maybe mark the lines you changed in some way.  Making me copy the original code and your answer so I can do a diff, and then figure out for myself why your answer works, makes the answer not very useful.